# JMeter software under test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing a seminar on JMeter and I need to demo on some software. My professor say we need an open source software. So that we can set it up on local host and testing against it

The problem is I don't know which open source software should be used. I am new to JMeter and saw some examples with testing a website only

So can anyone tell me some open source software that can be put under test with JMeter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for blog posts (wordpress, pizza in )which are simpler to use for demo purpose.

Comment: @NachiketKate Can u be more specific 'cause I have no experience with website programming or similar things such as WordPress??

Do u mean that I should use  a template of WordPress?

Comment: Yes. there are standard blog wordpress applications which you can use for demo purpose. http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, start with [this GitHub project](https://github.com/djangofan/run-jmeter-with-plugins-via-build-tools) and then, since the project includes [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), and requires [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to run, then you have 2 additional open source projects involved.   All you have to do is run JMeter using the included .bat script and then create a TestPlan with a JSR223-Groovy sampler in it.  (The project I mention above will launch a certain version of Jmeter 2.11)

You could also go one step further and install [PostgresSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) (also open source) and then create a JDBC sampler that connects to it using Jmeter  (because the Jmeter project I mentioned above also includes the postgres jdbc driver by default).

If you need a REST api to test against, then install [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on your local computer and you [can get Jmeter to perform rest queries against it](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/using-jenkins-hudson-remote-api-to-check-jobs-status.html).